# Get records in particular date range

Tags: c#

I have a column in database `DateCreated` that shows the creation date. Now I want to filter records depending on the date range selected. For example:

- created within 60 days
- created within month
- etc...

I have a variable `dateCreated` that shows me what the user has selected as the range, i.e. whether it is created within 60 days, created within year, and so on.

```
        DateTime CurrTime = DateTime.Now;
    if (Program.DateCreated <= DateTime.Now - 60)
    {
        //code to add the record goes here..
    }
```

But the above code wont work. What would be the syntax to get the records within a particular range?

Comment: When you say "Doesn't work", what do you mean? There's an error, or it doesn't return what you expect?

Comment: @rwmnau: My guess would be that he is getting this compile error: `Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'int'`

Comment: @Mark Byers - I'm sure you're a right. A little more looking and less asking would have gotten me than same answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a DateTime representing 60 days ago use this:

```
 DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60)
```

Note that it would probably be a better idea to send this query to the database rather than filtering on the client.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

`if (dateCreated >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(myTimeSpanRange))`

where myTimeSpanRange is a `TimeSpan` indicating how far back the user wants to go.

Answer (score 1):

To generate the TimeSpan Matt suggests, you could use this:

```
if (Program.DateCreated <= dateCreated - TimeSpan.FromDays(60)) {
   ...
}
```